# Produce output of previous year and month correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, getdate

This sql was created to check the date but when I run a test for 2 month ago the output is 201700 and not 201612.

```
DECLARE @PeriodID AS CHAR(6)
SELECT @PeriodID = CONVERT(char(4), YEAR(GETDATE())) +
CASE
      WHEN MONTH(GETDATE())<10 THEN '0' +CONVERT(char(2),MONTH(GETDATE())-2)
ELSE  CONVERT(char(2),MONTH(GETDATE())-1)
END
print @periodid
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard syntax used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Tim's answer, however the code he wrote is a bit combersome. 
The following code should provide the same result, using only one [`DateAdd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and one [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
DECLARE @PeriodID AS CHAR(6)
SELECT @PeriodID = CONVERT(CHAR(6), DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()), 112) 
PRINT  @PeriodID
```

Results (for today - 2017-02-02):

```
201612
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to handle this is just to compute the date for 2 months ago, and then format the output with only the year and month, as your question implies:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(4), YEAR(DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE()))) +
       RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())) AS CHAR(2)), 2) AS periodId
FROM yourTable
```